# EF:Many to many cascade delete

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-6

I have two entities that should have many to many relationship.I provide test data.

```
public class A
{
    public int AId {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
    public int BId {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<A> As {get;set;}
}

public class AMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<A>
{
    public AMap()
    {
        HasMany(e => e.Bs)
            .WithMany(e => e.As)                
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.ToTable("AandB");
                x.MapLeftKey("AId");
                x.MapRightKey("BId");
            });
    }

}
```

In this configuration I need set cascade delete.For example when I delete any row in table A,I need that all related rows in table AandB will be deleted.But I can't find syntax for many to many.Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching I've found solution.To delete entity from many-to-many relationship you need **load the related navigation property**
In my case:

```
var AtoDelete= context.As.Include(a => a.Bs) .First(); //include is mandatory
context.As.Remove(AtoDelete);
context.SaveChanges();//deletes will be issued to AandB table also.
```